# how to create a library by using visual studio 2012 in C/C++ lan

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a library where I can reuse my *.lib.

I have written my fully optimized algorithm and want to create a library for the same.
My algorithm is in C language. I have created library in VS2012 and output of my solution is in *.exe format.

I want the output in *.lib format.

Can you help me in this?

Comment: Did you try the msdn docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: Thanks Brandin.Thanks for the above link !!!